# REST Authentication with Username and Password to receive Token

Tags: web-services, api, rest, authentication

I have a dataprovider with a REST service. They said that the authentication goes as follows:

```
1. Username and Password are passed in the request header
2. If the authentication is successful I get a token which I have to store and use this token to make further requests.
```

Now I started reading into [REST Authentication](http://www.jamiekurtz.com/2013/01/14/asp-net-web-api-security-basics/) and just do not understand what kind of authentication they use. I guess I have missunderstood something, so please correct me.

There are three kinds of authentication

```
1. Basic Authentication (sending username and password base 64 encoded in the header)
2. OpenID (here I send my username and password to a provider to receive a token)
3. OAuth (The caller is identified with a trusted token to let application call another application on a end-user's behalf without requiring the calling application to store the users's username and password)
```

I cannnot see, where to classify my providers method. 1. I am not sending UserName Password everytime. 2. I do not use a provider, 3. I am not doing application calls and do not use only tokens. Could anyone help me here?

Comment: You need more documentation from your provider.

Answer (score 0):

When you send username and password to provider if correct, provider will create a token for this user and this token will be sent to you by provider.

After this, you can use this token in any session and you can check only this token for expiration, you do not have to send username and password everytime.